# Stacking columns and images in Bootstrap responsive design

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I want to stack four images which are next to each other at desktop size, to be above each other in 2 columns (1 and 2 
 3 and 4) in mobile screen size, using the bootstrap 12 column grid. The original 4 imgs are similar but are not exactly the same in size. The heights vary between 40 and 57 px and the widths are between 176 and 220 px. When displayed non-responsive they come out the way they should in desktop size, next to each other. However, when I make them responsive by adding width=100% in the html, the last one comes out magnified compared to the rest, both in desktop and in mobile size, and the first one takes up more space than the rest if I inspect them. The pics do line up in 2 columns in mobile size, but the last pic is not in line with the third one but displaced a paragraph below. If I adjust the size of the last pic to 85% then the sizes are okay, but issue with the pic being out of position still remains.

Here is the code:

```
<section id="section">
        <div class = "container">
            <div class = "row">
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 col text-center">
                <img src = "img/1.png" style='width:100%;'  alt="Null" />
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 text-center">
                <img src = "img/2.png" style='width:100%;'  alt="Null" />                    
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 text-center">
                <img src = "img/3.png" style='width:100%;'  alt="Null" />
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 text-center">
                <img src = "img/4.png" style='width:100%;' alt="Null" />
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Start with a minimal example like this http://bootply.com/mjMkQHvC3m __ it's really hard to help w/o knowing the image sizes

Answer (score 0):

It depends by use of `float` on items of different height.

You have 2 options, one adding a special div provided by Bootstrap, that is visible only in mobile breakpoints:

```
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 text-center">
            <img src = "img/2.png" style='width:100%;'  alt="Null" />                    
            </div>


            <div class="clearfix visible-xs"></div>

            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 text-center">
            <img src = "img/3.png" style='width:100%;'  alt="Null" />
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 text-center">
            <img src = "img/4.png" style='width:100%;' alt="Null" />
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You have to add it after each two elements.

Another solution is to set auto-clear with only css (you have to manually set the right media query value) and the idea is to `clear:left` every 3rd element:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 720px) {
    .col-xs-6:nth-of-type(2n+1) {
        clear:left;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I can't help with that, cause my reputation is too low for either. Thanks again.

Comment: Ok, maybe you could remember me when you'll have enough reputation :D